# ESXi (auto-)backup keys-<user> (for new user)

Tags: vmware-esxi

I am setting up a certificate connection under ESXi 6.7u3 through another user in order not to use the root account.This account allows me to execute ssh commands via cron task from another machine.

ESXi running in ramdisk, which poses a problem for me to backup my `keys-<user>/authorized_keys` folder and restore it when restarting the hypervisor.

I set the sticky bit to T with `chown +t`, and the `ls -la` tells me so, but after manually restarting the `/sbin/auto-backup.sh` script, my `keys-<user>/*` folder is not added to the state.tgz archive.

For information, if I do a `chown +t of keys-root/authorized_keys, this one is well saved...

Do you have a solution?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Why do you want to execute ssh commands via cron task in the first place? And how do you mean 'ESXi running in ramdisk'? It sounds like you're trying to do something it wasn't meant to do.

Comment: ESXi runs on ramdisk, that's how it works. When you make changes, the /etc/ directory is backed up by a /sbin/auto-backup.sh script that creates a state.tgz archive that is restored when the hypervisor is booted or restarted.


I have a VM to backup that needs to be turned off. I use an SSH command to restart this VM at the end of the backup.

Comment: "ESXi runs on ramdisk" - sorry but no it doesn't, not unless you PXE-boot it anyway, it does use a ramdisk yes but there's also persistant partitions it uses too, that's where it stores its IP/hostname etc. Why aren't you just using vCenter to do all this?

Comment: What I've been able to read and what I can see is that my keys-<user> folder is not restored because it's not backed up. More information here https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/2001780 and here https://communities.vmware.com/message/2557808#2557808

Comment: So I temporarily work around the problem by renaming the key-root folder to keys-<user> so that this folder contains the .#authorized_keys, so it is saved. More information here https://www.virtuallyghetto.com/2011/08/how-to-persist-configuration-changes-in.html Of course, if one day I ever need the keys-root, I'll have to find an alternative...

Answer (score 1):

I came to the following workaround since the `/sbin/auto-backup.sh` script didn't add the `keys-<user>/*` folder to the state.tgz archive:

1. Create the `/etc/ssh/keys-<user>` folder and the `/etc/ssh/keys-<user>/authorized_keys` file so that ssh commands can be executed from another machine (I won't go into details about this step, since there is enough documentation online about this)
2. Let's suppose that there is a `/vmfs/volumes/XXXXXXXX` volume. Create a tar of the `/etc/ssh/keys-<user>` folder:

   ```
   tar cvf /vmfs/volumes/XXXXXXXX/keys-<user>.tar /etc/ssh/keys-<user>
   ```
3. Create a shell script file e.g. `/vmfs/volumes/XXXXXXXX/keys-<user>.sh`:

   ```
   #!/bin/sh

   tar xvf  /vmfs/volumes/XXXXXXXX/keys-<user>.tar  -C /
   ```
4. Make this shell script executable:

   ```
   chmod +x /vmfs/volumes/XXXXXXXX/keys-<user>.sh
   ```
5. Add this shell script in the `/etc/rc.local.d/local.sh`:

   ```
   #!/bin/sh

   # ...

   /vmfs/volumes/XXXXXXXX/keys-<user>.sh

   exit 0
   ```

The `/vmfs/volumes/XXXXXXXX/keys-<user>.sh` shell script will be executed upon every boot of the ESXi host and the the `/etc/ssh/keys-<user>` folder and the `/etc/ssh/keys-<user>/authorized_keys` file will be restored.